# Live data for series's Y Axis in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

My Y Axis count votes for a performer, something like :

1. Mr. X voted 3 times
2. Mr.Y voted 5 times
3. Mrs.Z voted 10 times

So Mrs.Z will be the highest data in Y Axis.

This is some snippet of my `Highchart` code :

```
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Votes'
                    }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'Performer',
                    data: [<?php echo $comma_chartY ?>]
                }]
```

The line `data: [<?php echo $comma_chartY ?>]` will generate this result :

```
data: [1,2,4,0,0]
```

Now, supposed the first performer is voted again (most left), the data should be like this :

```
data: [2,2,4,0,0]
```

And my `Highchart` should be refreshed.

Could anyone guide me how to accomplish this?

I google but what i found is live stream example for X-Axis series.

Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: did you tried to using update function ?

Comment: You can use [point.update](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update) function

Comment: @NishithChaturvedi Thanks for the reply. Could you give me a clue how to use this `update` function to dynamically update my Y Axis?

Comment: @SebastianBochan Thanks for the reply. I think `point.update` will add a `series` instead of the Y Axis. Could you give me a clue, how to done this with `point.update` function?

Comment: try using this way       :  chart.series[0].update({
    
    data: yourUpdatedData
}, true);